# How to fix blog post collecting in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a blog..

Earlier the article URLs were as follows:

`sitename.com/blog/article-name.aspx`

and were automatically grouped by Google Analytics (Behavior - Site content- Content drilldown). Each URL had a `/blog/` part, so the grouping was perfect.

Now all the blog article URLs are `sitename.com/article-name`

So they are not grouped in "Content drilldown (`/blog/` was removed from the URL structure). We can't put it back.

Also URL parameters (fbclid and some other) make doubles of blog pages.

In Nov-Dec we updated the CMS, now we don't have any `.aspx` in URLs

But some of the articles were published earlier, so we changed the URLs from "/article.aspx” to “/article”

What we need:

- Well-done report (similar to Content drilldown) containing all the blog articles. Not just URLs, but page names (from page title).
- All new articles should be automatically added to this report.
- URL parameters should be ignored.
- Make it like Article stats = older article stats (`/article.aspx`) + new article stats (`/article`)

How can we make this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to identify an article as opposed to a none article from a dev point of view?

Pass a custom dimension with the hit for articles, then use that custom dimension to create the report. 
Ask the developers to add in a dataLayer variable on the pageview, or a local js variable you can use to identify a pageview type as "blog" or "whatever" and send that with the analytics hit.

Answer (score 0):

Content group i guess will be the easiest and best option in your case: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en Check: "Create a Content Group via the tracking code" section on this page (developer help will be needed).

Of course as ASomN said: sending additional custom dimension (with pageview hit) will be nice addon.